# I cant run my ReactJS app in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

It works when i run npm start, but in heroku i cant do it works,

```js
2017-06-28T17:18:54.167693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2017-06-28T17:18:54.167918+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2017-06-28T17:18:54.168018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2017-06-28T17:18:54.168132+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! juego-cartas-reactjs@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2017-06-28T17:18:54.168203+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2017-06-28T17:18:54.168300+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2017-06-28T17:18:54.168387+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the juego-cartas-reactjs@0.1.0 start script.
2017-06-28T17:18:54.169487+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-06-28T17:18:54.168480+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2017-06-28T17:18:54.169649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2017-06-28T17:18:54.169703+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2017-06-28T17_18_54_163Z-debug.log
```

my package.json, i saw on internet that maybe here is the problem

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    {
      "name": "juego-cartas-reactjs",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "main":"src/index.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "lodash.shuffle": "^4.2.0",
        "react": "^15.6.1",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
        "react-flipcard": "^0.2.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
      },

      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

I dont know what else to do, if anyone know something about this, help

Comment: Did you run a `npm install` on the server to make sure that `react-scripts` exists? Looks like that's where it's failing.

Comment: you mean in the console of my heroku project app?

Comment: Yep exactly! Check out [their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs) for more help.

Comment: i think that is not the problem, because i run npm start in my app, and it works properly

Comment: Yes because you have all of your dependencies installed locally. Do this, go into your app and delete the `node_modules` folder. Then run `npm start` and you should get the same error. Then, run `npm install` and then `npm start` and it should start working again. Wherever the app is running, the dependencies need to be downloaded and installed.

Comment: did it, and now when i open the app with heroku, in my case https://cards-game-heroku.herokuapp.com/, it crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've uploaded a create-react-app project successfully on heroku and I didn't use the create-react-app buildpack. Here is my setup:

**package.json**

```js
//.. rest of package.json

"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.14.0",
  //.. rest of dependencies 
},

// need to define engines for heroku
"engines": {
  "node": "6.9.1",
  "npm": "3.10.8"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js #Production only!",
  "postinstall": "npm run build",
  "dev": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Then in the root directory of the project, I created a server.js, which is just a pretty basic express app. Note that it uses the **build** folder and not the **src** folder.

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.info(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`npm start` is **only** for local development. You shouldn't be using it on Heroku.

To deploy a Create React App project to Heroku [follow Heroku's official guide to it](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration).

```
cd my-app
git init
heroku create -b https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
git add .
git commit -m "react-create-app on Heroku"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

This article is linked from [Deployment section of the User Guide](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment) that ships with your created app. I recommend searching for possible answers there.

Comment: this actually doesnt work for me... the app still crashing when i try tu run it in heroku...